# What is the physics behind distorted wave Born approximation?

Tags: nuclear-physics

If distorted wave Born approximation is used to account for nuclear couplings, then does that signify that nuclear couplings are only upto the first order?

Comment: Approximations are motivated by underlying physics, and not the other way round as asked in your question.. As for your question, it should be more like whether second order terms are negligible or not in the approximation, and that depends on exact system in question.

Comment: Okay. Consider inelastic scattering of nuclei. How does DWBA explain that?